# How can I use version 2.0 of Tensorflow in python 3.7.9 and use the displacement function?

Tags: tensorflow, module, placeholder, attributeerror

I was following a tutorial by this guy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PwAGxqrXSCs&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfKTOs3Keq_kaG2P55YRn5v&index=47 , and now I have run into a Error.
The programm tells me : "AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'". I know that in version 2.0 and higher (of tensorflow) the placeholder function got removed, however I am unable to figure out another way of making my script work as I am just starting out with Deep Learning! Help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code (I am using PyCharm as an IDE, dont know if thats a source for the Error):

```
import tensorflow as tf

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

#Hidden Layers
n_nodes_hl1 = 500 # Can be different from others (they do no HAVE to be the same number)
n_nodes_hl2 = 500
n_nodes_hl3 = 500

n_classes = 10
batch_size = 100


#Input Data
#Height x width

x = tf.placeholder('float',[None, 784])
y = tf.placeholder('float')


def neural_network_model(data):

    #(Input_data * weights) + biases
    #Why need biases?
    #If Input_Data = 0 and weights = (ANYTHING) and there was no bias, no neuron would ever fire!
    #Because ofcourse (0 * (ANYTHING)) = 0


    hidden_1_layer = {"weights":tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([784, n_nodes_hl1])),
                      "biases":tf.Variable(tf.random.normal(n_nodes_hl1))}

    hidden_2_layer = {"weights":tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
                      "biases":tf.Variable(tf.random.normal(n_nodes_hl2))}

    hidden_3_layer = {"weights":tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])),
                      "biases":tf.Variable(tf.random.normal(n_nodes_hl3))}

    output_layer = {"weights":tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_nodes_hl3, n_classes])),
                      "biases":tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_classes]))}

    # (Input_data * weights) + biases

    #This is the Sum thingy l1(layer 1)
    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data * hidden_1_layer["weights"]), hidden_1_layer["biases"])
    #Threshold function (will neuron fire?) [relu] = rectified linear
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

    #This is the Sum thingy for l2
    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1 * hidden_2_layer["weights"]), hidden_2_layer["biases"])
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

    #This is the Sum thingy for l3
    l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2 * hidden_3_layer["weights"]), hidden_3_layer["biases"])
    l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

    #This is the Sum thingy
    output = tf.matmul(l3 * output_layer["weights"]) + output_layer["biases"]

    return output


def train_neural_network(x):
        prediction = neural_network_model(x)

        #Calculates the difference between prediction and known label
        cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=y))

        #No we know what the cost is, LETS MINIMZE IT!

        #                                   learning_rate = 0.001
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

        #How many epochs do we want? (How often does it run) (Cycles feed forward + backprop)
        hm_epochs = 100
        with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            
            #This trains:
            for epoch in hm_epochs:
                epoch_loss = 0

                for _ in range(int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)):
                    x, y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
                    _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict = {x: x, y: y})
                    epoch_loss += c
                print("Epoch", epoch, "Completed out of", hm_epochs, "loss:",epoch_loss)


        #This checks if the machine does stuff right
            #Checks if the maximum number is identical to the machines prediction
            correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y,1))

            accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, "float"))
            print("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x:mnist.test.images, y:mnist.test.labels}))
            


train_neural_network(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Tenosrflow 2 you can use tf.compat.v1.placeholder(), this is not compatible with `eager execution` and `tf.function`.

If you want to explicitly set up your inputs, also see `Keras functional API` on how to use `tf.keras.Input` to replace `tf.compat.v1.placeholder`.

Example,

```
x = tf.keras.Input(shape=(32,))
```